# "Restrict" text scaling on zoom chart

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

The issue is the following:
 we have some tooltips on the chart, on zooming the chart they translate accordingly, i.e. keep their position related to the chart elements,  but the size of the tooltip and its text should not scale. Now everything scales, both tooltip and text and it is correct in general but somehow we have to reset the scaled text to keep it readable or find the way to calculate the correct position.

Thank you.

Comment: You could redraw the labels with an adjusted font size when the graph is zoomed.

Comment: Hello, @LarsKotthoff, yes this works with more or less satisfying results, thanks you.

Comment: Great, I'll post that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to zooming the generated SVG as-is would be to redraw the labels with adjusted font size when the graph is zoomed. This way, you can preserve their relative size.